# Matrix formulation of Number-theoretic transforms (NTT)

Tags: number-theory

I have two polynomials over a finite field. I am trying to compute the product of these polynomials using Number-theoretic transforms. For my use case, it makes sense to do this in the matrix form.

What is the matrix formulation of the NTT and inverse-NTT? Does it
differ from the DFT and inverse-DFT
[matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform_(general)#Matrix_formulation)?

Comment: And where does this related to Cryptography? NTT is for the finite fields, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1182734/338051

Comment: See [further down the page that you link to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform_(general)#Number-theoretic_transform). The number theoretic transform is the discrete Fourier transform when the roots of unity are interpreted modulo $p$ for some prime $p$.